# deploy web apps /create Stages by api to run new deployments

Tags: azure-devops

It’ possible to create a deploment stage by Azure DevOps API? We want to create a new stage and want to deploy a web app on the webserver. What is the best approach to release a new web app including the configuration of iis by azure devops API?

Kind Regards,

Dominik

Answer (score 0):

If you mean creating release definition with stages and specific tasks, then you can call the [Definitions - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) REST API.

For example to add a stage with the [IIS Web App Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-deployment-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops):

```
POST : https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0
```

Request Body: (Of course, you need to replace the parameters accordingly. You can also capture the `Request Body`(Payload) by pressing F12 when creating a release definition from the UI)

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "RESTAPI-WEB",
    "source": 2,
    "comment": "",
    "createdOn": "2022-04-20T08:36:03.598Z",
    "createdBy": null,
    "modifiedBy": null,
    "modifiedOn": "2022-04-20T08:36:03.598Z",
    "environments": [
        {
            "id": -3,
            "name": "Stage 1",
            "rank": 1,
            "variables": {},
            "variableGroups": [],
            "preDeployApprovals": {
                "approvals": [
                    {
                        "rank": 1,
                        "isAutomated": true,
                        "isNotificationOn": false,
                        "id": 0
                    }
                ],
                "approvalOptions": {
                    "executionOrder": 1
                }
            },
            "deployStep": {
                "tasks": [],
                "id": 0
            },
            "postDeployApprovals": {
                "approvals": [
                    {
                        "rank": 1,
                        "isAutomated": true,
                        "isNotificationOn": false,
                        "id": 0
                    }
                ],
                "approvalOptions": {
                    "executionOrder": 2
                }
            },
            "deployPhases": [
                {
                    "deploymentInput": {
                        "parallelExecution": {
                            "parallelExecutionType": 0
                        },
                        "agentSpecification": null,
                        "skipArtifactsDownload": false,
                        "artifactsDownloadInput": {},
                        "queueId": 158,
                        "demands": [],
                        "enableAccessToken": false,
                        "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                        "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 1,
                        "condition": "succeeded()",
                        "overrideInputs": {},
                        "dependencies": []
                    },
                    "rank": 1,
                    "phaseType": 1,
                    "name": "Agent job",
                    "refName": null,
                    "workflowTasks": [
                        {
                            "name": "Deploy IIS Website/App: ",
                            "refName": null,
                            "enabled": true,
                            "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                            "inputs": {
                                "WebSiteName": "TestSite",
                                "VirtualApplication": "",
                                "Package": "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\\**\\*.zip",
                                "SetParametersFile": "",
                                "RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag": "true",
                                "ExcludeFilesFromAppDataFlag": "true",
                                "TakeAppOfflineFlag": "false",
                                "AdditionalArguments": "",
                                "XmlTransformation": "false",
                                "XmlVariableSubstitution": "false",
                                "JSONFiles": ""
                            },
                            "taskId": "1b467810-6725-4b6d-accd-886174c09bba",
                            "version": "0.*",
                            "definitionType": "task",
                            "alwaysRun": false,
                            "continueOnError": false,
                            "overrideInputs": {},
                            "condition": "succeeded()",
                            "environment": {},
                            "retryCountOnTaskFailure": 0
                        }
                    ],
                    "phaseInputs": {}
                }
            ],
            "runOptions": {},
            "environmentOptions": {
                "emailNotificationType": "OnlyOnFailure",
                "emailRecipients": "release.environment.owner;release.creator",
                "skipArtifactsDownload": false,
                "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                "enableAccessToken": false,
                "publishDeploymentStatus": true,
                "badgeEnabled": false,
                "autoLinkWorkItems": false,
                "pullRequestDeploymentEnabled": false
            },
            "demands": [],
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "conditionType": 1,
                    "name": "ReleaseStarted",
                    "value": ""
                }
            ],
            "executionPolicy": {
                "concurrencyCount": 1,
                "queueDepthCount": 0
            },
            "schedules": [],
            "properties": {
                "LinkBoardsWorkItems": false,
                "BoardsEnvironmentType": "unmapped"
            },
            "preDeploymentGates": {
                "id": 0,
                "gatesOptions": null,
                "gates": []
            },
            "postDeploymentGates": {
                "id": 0,
                "gatesOptions": null,
                "gates": []
            },
            "retentionPolicy": {
                "daysToKeep": 30,
                "releasesToKeep": 3,
                "retainBuild": true
            },
            "processParameters": {}
        }
    ],
    "artifacts": [
        {
            "type": "Build",
            "definitionReference": {
                "IsMultiDefinitionType": {
                    "name": "False",
                    "id": "False"
                },
                "project": {
                    "name": "AzureFunction",
                    "id": "4da2f07a-ac7b-43a0-b764-459af8a4d9df"
                },
                "repository": {
                    "name": "",
                    "id": ""
                },
                "definitions": {
                    "name": "",
                    "id": ""
                },
                "definition": {
                    "name": "AzureFunctions_CI",
                    "id": "172"
                },
                "defaultVersionType": {
                    "name": "Latest",
                    "id": "latestType"
                },
                "defaultVersionBranch": {
                    "name": "",
                    "id": ""
                },
                "defaultVersionTags": {
                    "name": "",
                    "id": ""
                },
                "defaultVersionSpecific": {
                    "name": "",
                    "id": ""
                }
            },
            "alias": "_AzureFunctions_CI",
            "isPrimary": true,
            "sourceId": "",
            "isRetained": false
        }
    ],
    "variables": {},
    "variableGroups": [],
    "triggers": [],
    "lastRelease": null,
    "tags": [],
    "path": "\\",
    "properties": {
        "DefinitionCreationSource": "ReleaseNew",
        "IntegrateJiraWorkItems": "false",
        "IntegrateBoardsWorkItems": false
    },
    "releaseNameFormat": "Release-$(rev:r)",
    "description": ""
}
```

To deploy the webapp, please refer to [Deploy your Web Deploy package to IIS servers using WinRM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-winrm?view=azure-devops) and [Deploy an Azure Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows%2Cyaml) for details.